# Filter product loop based on user dynamic product attribute value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

How do I modify the main loop of WooCommerce to filter based on a logged in user's ACF field? I have added a new field to the user profile using ACF, it pulls a select list from a product attribute (Vehicle Year). I want to make it so products only show up for the user based on what vehicle year they've chosen. I can't figure out how to modify the loop so no matter what WooCommerce page the customer views it will be filtered to only show products with the attribute that matches the Vehicle Year selected in their user profile.

I added the following code to the archive-products.php page to check for the logged in user. If you have a better idea, I'm open.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
    $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
    $uid = $user->ID;
$year = get_field("vehicle-year", "user_$uid");
echo $year->name;
}
```

This helped me confirm I can get the ACF field based on the user logged in.

I know I need something that has something like this, I'm just not sure how to make it replace/attach to the main WooCommerce loop so it's always filtering the products.

```
'tax_query' => array(
        'relation'=>'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_year-2',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => '1970'
        )
    )
```

Appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following with this dedicated WooCommerce hook:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_tax_query', 20, 2 );
function custom_product_query_tax_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    // Only on front end for logged in users
    if( is_admin() || ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $tax_query;

    // HERE get and Define the product attribute term name (from user data) to be used
    $term  = get_field( "vehicle-year", 'user_' . get_current_user_id() ); // Get the year (term)
    $terms = array( $term->name );

    // The taxonomy for your product attribute
    $taxonomy = 'pa_year-2';

    $tax_query['relation'] = 'AND'; // Not really necessary as it's defined by default
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field'    => 'name', // 'term_id', 'slug' or 'name'
        'terms'    => $terms,
    );

    return $tax_query;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* It should work.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried it and got "No products were found matching your selection." I noticed the comment above $terms = array('1970') says "excluded". We want to only show products with that attribute term. Maybe it's just a typo in the comment. Any idea why we'd get the message that there are no products? It should display 1,448 products.

Comment: I figured out that the line that is suppose to get the "vehicle-year" based on the current user id isn't working. If I just do the testing example for $terms it works fine.

`$terms = array( get_field( "vehicle-year", get_current_user_id() ) );`

Comment: I believe I found the issue, but now I have to figure out how to fix it correctly. You have `$terms = array( get_field( "vehicle-year", get_current_user_id() ) );` however ACF requires "user_" to be attached to the user ID [link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/). Plus when viewing how I echoed the year next to the Welcome text, I have to take the result and get the term name `$year->name`